# How to Create ExtJS Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

I tried the below code to create google map but didn't work. I am working on ExtJS 5.2.

**Here is my code:**

```
{
    xtype: 'mapPanel',
    title: 'Google Map',
    align: 'middle',
    padding: 10,
    pack: 'center',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'map',
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
        mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom', 'enableDoubleClickZoom', 'enableDragging'],
        mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl', 'GMapTypeControl', 'NonExistantControl'],
        center: {
            geoCodeAddr: '4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA, 02215-3409, USA',
            marker: {
                title: 'Fenway Park'
            }
        },
        markers: [{
            lat: 42.339641,
            lng: -71.094224,
            title: 'Boston Museum of Fine Arts',
            listeners: {
                click: function (e) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');
                }
            }
        }, {
            lat: 42.339419,
            lng: -71.09077,
            title: 'Northeastern University'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: xtype: 'map' belongs to the 6 version and up

Comment: Why my question is down voted?

Answer (score 2):

In `ExtJS 5.x` you need to use `xtype: gmappanel`.

**Make sure you are including below script tag in your index.html before bootstrap/microloader:-**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>`

**And require `GMapPanel`:**

`Ext.require('Ext.ux.GMapPanel');`

**Code snippet:**

```
{
    xtype: 'gmappanel',
    center: {
        lat: 22.785639,
        lng: 72.549574
    },
    mapOptions: {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        zoom: 6
    },
    markers: [{
        lat: 22.785639,
        lng: 72.549574,
        title: 'Ahmedabad',
        listeners: {
            click: function (e) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');
            }
        }
    }, {
        lat: 22.643760,
        lng: 75.845472,
        title: 'Indore'
    }]
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jf9)

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help but I didn't find the Ext.ux.gmappanel required file in my ExtJS framework 5.1.1 GPL.

Comment: I am getting this error and only showing on the browser blank screen no display Google Map:                                                                                            
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of null.                          
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStyle' of null

Comment: Share [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have tried so far.